# Finding coefficients of a polynomial from a given relationship

Tags: polynomials

I wouldn’t have thought that I would stumble upon my son's math homework question on polynomials, yet I do not recall seeing this type of question before. Is the question misworded, or am I terribly missing something?

> Given that (1) $\frac{x-2 \cdot P(x)}{x \cdot Q(x-2) - 3} = 2x^5 - 1$,
>   and (2) $Q(x)$ divided by $(x+1)$ gives a remainder of 2; what is the
>   sum of the coefficients of $P(x)$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Putting $x=1$ we get:

$$\frac{1-2P(1)}{Q(-1) -3} =1,$$

but $Q(-1) =2$ thus $$P(1)=1.$$

Comment: Now I get it. I needed to think in terms of $P(1)$.